# Ruby send and receive custom TCP packets using PacketFu

Tags: ruby, sockets, tcp

I have a server running on port 3000 and a simple ruby program that reads lines from the server

```
require 'socket'
require 'packetfu'

s = TCPSocket.open('localhost', 3000)

config = PacketFu::Config.new(:iface=> "wlan0").config
pkt = PacketFu::TCPPacket.new(:config => $config , :flavor => "Linux")

while line = s.gets   
  puts line.chop     
end
s.close
```

**Server**

```
require 'socket'               

server = TCPServer.open('localhost', 3000)  
loop {                         
  client = server.accept       
  client.close                 
}
```

I want to build a simple TCP packet using [packetfu](https://github.com/packetfu/packetfu) that sends a WAKE-UP call and receive ACK from the server. What changes should i make to build this packet and receive the response?